# Create a way to "tag" people in PHP messsage system

Tags: php, mysql, tags, message

I'm building a simple web app with PHP and Mysql. One of it's features is a page where all of the users can exchange messages with a textarea inside a form.

On the side of the textarea, i have a div with the pictures of all registed users. When writing a message, you can click on one the users' image and the name of the user will be written in the textarea.

How can i do a "tag" system in PHP so that when a user uses this feature and "tags" someone in a message, it will look for that name in a mySql table and then send a notification for a user?

I'm not asking for an answer with all the specific code to achieve this, just logic guidelines on how to do this. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you currently have a notification system implemented?

Comment: @clabe45 Yes, i do. I just don't know how to make a PHP script that will search for users that have been tagged in a message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new database table of tags/notifications with at a minimum the User ID of the recipient, message, sent timestamp and read timestamp.

Have your script check this table and show notifications matching that user ID with no read timestamp. Once the user clicks the notification, you can insert the read timestamp in to the row to hide it.

To keep the database tidy, you could create an extra script perhaps a cron to clear all read notifications after a week. :)

Comment: The notification system itself i think i know how to do it. I already have something similar in this web app. My doubt is, how do i make a script that will know that a user has been tagged in a message?

Comment: Create a script that runs when the page loads to get the users ID and compare it with user IDs in the notifications database.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not being able to explain myself properly. I'll try this way:

- Imagine i have 3 users on the 'Users' table that has a field called 'Full_Name'. One of the users has the the Id:1 and full_name: John Doe.

If i write a message like: "Hey guys, what's up? John Doe, are you okay?" How can i create a new notification for the user with the id = 1 just because their name was written in a comment?

Comment: Hmm.. that will be resource intensive if you don't have some kind of marker such as an @ symbol but when the message is submitted you could search the message for full names when it is submitted. You can use PHP strpos for this which will return a true/false, you would have to run through each name in the database which is not feasible for more than a handful of users.

Comment: If you had it so users had to prepend an @ to names then you could just check the message for that first and only search for names afterwards which would save a lot of time on messages that tag nobody.

What if 2 people have the same full name? Tagging a username would be better. :)

Comment: Yeah, i can add an '@'. I was thinking about this. How do i do then? Just create a scipt that searches for this symbol and then selects the characters following this symbol?

Comment: This web app will be used by a specific amount of people that i know so there won't be equal full names :)

Comment: Yeah that's right, although determining where to stop looking will be difficult if the full names have spaces in. If it was usernames you could grab anything between an @ and a space using regex and compare that with the database. If you absolutely know that full names will have 1 space exactly in, then you could just search for the 2nd space/full stop/comma. I'm sure there is some regex magic for this although that is a weak point for me!

Comment: Okay then, i think i will the use the username field since it contains no spaces. Thanks for being so helpfull Adam. Cheers!

Comment: No problem, hope it goes well! If you are happy please accept as answer.